# Is there any way to register a callback for deletions in a capped collection in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I want to use a capped collection in Mongo, but I don't want my documents to die when the collection loops around. Instead, I want Mongo to notice that I'm running out of space and move the old documents into another, permanent collection for archival purposes.

Is there a way to have Mongo do this automatically, or can I register a callback that would perform this action?

Comment: Just a curiosity, why use a capped collection at all?

Comment: I recently learned about capped collections. I thought there was some performance benefit to them, but it sounds like the true benefit is simply the auto-deletion of older documents. Is that true?

Comment: They should be a bit faster, but you do not have the ability to shard, but there is an issue about that here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2654 . As @Remon van Vliet said the data you use most will have hight availability even if you have tons of other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a capped collection for this. I'm assuming you're doing so because you want to keep the amount of "hot" data relatively small and move stale data to a permanent collection. However, this is effectively what happens anyway when you use MongoDB. Data that's accessed often will be in memory and data that is used less often will not be. Same goes for your indexes if they remain right-balanced. I would think you're doing a bit of premature optimization or at least have a suboptimal schema or index strategy for your problem. If you post exactly what you're trying to achieve and where your performance takes a dive I can have a look.

To answer your actual question; MongoDB does not have callbacks or triggers. There are some open feature requests for them though.

EDIT (Small elaboration on technical implementation) : MongoDB is built on top of memory mapped files for it's storage engine. It basically means it's an LRU based cache of "hot" data where data in this case can be both actual data and index data. As a result data and associated index data you access often (in your case the data you'd typically have in your capped collection) will be in memory and thus very fast to query. In typical use cases the performance difference between having an "active" collection and an "archive" collection and just one big collection should be small. As you can imagine having more memory available to the mongod process means more data can stay in memory and as a result performance will improve. There are some nice presentations from 10gen available on mongodb.org that go into more detail and also provide detail on how to keep indexes right balanced etc.

Comment: There is no existing schema yet -- I'm just trying to learn about Mongo concepts. From what you're saying, it sounds like capped collections are not necessary for me.

Comment: Okay. In that case I'll elaborate my answer a bit on why this (usually) takes care of itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, MongoDB does not support triggers at all. If you want to move documents away before they reach the end of the "cap" then you need to monitor the data usage yourself.

However, I don't see why you would want a capped collection and also still want to move your items away. If you clarify that in your question, I'll update the answer.